# making new directory in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, directory, mkdir

I'm new to Ubuntu (18.04 LTS) and need to install a software (Juliapro) on it. based on the manual, I installed the per-requisit by TERMINAL, but for installing the script file in below path

```
>>  chmod 777 JuliaPro-0.6.3.1.sh

>> ./JuliaPro-0.6.3.1.sh /home/julia/
```

this error appears:

```
>> Installing JuliaPro-0.6.3.1 to /home/julia/
>> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/julia/’: Permission denied
>> tar: /home/julia: Cannot open: No such file or directory
>> tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>> /tmp/self-extract-bash.sy4y22/install_juliapro.sh: line 113: cd: /home/julia//JuliaPro-0.6.3.1/Scripts: No such file or directory
```

However I'm in admin account, I'm not familiar with how allow it to create the directory.

Comment: `/home` is traditionally reserved for the home directories of real users - I don't see any good reason for software to be installed there. If it's personal use software, I'd suggest `/home/<username>/julia` (or equivalently `$HOME/julia`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/home/julia/` is the name of a directory of a new user named `julia` and it looks like you have not created this new user yet, causing the permissions errors. The JuliaPro-0.6.3.1.sh script takes one optional argument, the absolute path to the directory into which you want to install JuliaPro. So install JuliaPro the normal way using `sudo` without the optional argument and let the JuliaPro-0.6.3.1.sh installer script create whatever default directories that it needs for you.

In Ubuntu 18.04 run the following commands:

```
sudo apt install gcc python2.7-dev curl libzmq5 hdf5-tools python libgconf-2-4 default-jdk  
sudo chmod 777 JuliaPro-0.6.3.1.sh  
sudo ./JuliaPro-0.6.3.1.sh
```

If you want to complicate matters by creating a custom directory to install JuliaPro in, create it manually using `mkdir` if the new directory is located in a directory not owned by root or `sudo mkdir` if it is located in a directory owned by root. Otherwise simply allow the installer script to create whatever default directories that it needs.

Execution of the installer script will show the directory into which installation is occurring. Upon completion of the installer, the contents of the JuliaPro installation directory can be viewed. To launch a JuliaPro command prompt from the terminal, one needs
to launch the julia binary included within the JuliaPro distribution.
The julia binary can be executed from the terminal with the following command:

```
$ <juliapro>/JuliaPro-0.6.3.1/julia
```

...where `<juliapro>` is the JuliaPro installation path.

Reference: [JuliaPro (v0.6.3.1) Installation Manual and Quickstart Guide](https://juliacomputing.com/docs/JuliaProQuickStartGuide-Linux.pdf)

Comment: Your advice is straight forward compare to  manual for newcomers. I installed it however some errors appeared through installing but at the end it was written the JuliaPro installation completed. and I could run $ <juliapro>/JuliaPro-0.6.3.1/julia

Comment: I agree with you that the manual is confusing and it also needs to be updated and contains spelling errors.